# Why isn't this a valid method to create a default struct instance in C?

Tags: c

So suppose I have the following two files:

```c
// main.h

struct Player {

    int health;
    int stamina;

};
```

```c
// main.c

#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    struct Player newPlayer;
    newPlayer.health = 100;
    newPlayer.stamina = 100;

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine.

Now suppose I have these two files:

```c
// main.h

struct Player {

    int health;
    int stamina;

};

struct Player defaultPlayer;
defaultPlayer.health = 100;  // error here
defaultPlayer.stamina = 100; // error here
```

```c
// main.c

#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    struct Player newPlayer = defaultPlayer;
    return 0;
}
```

The error in question is:

```
Unknown type name 'defaultPlayer'
[clang: unknown_typename]
```

My question is: Why can't I define a default `struct` in the `.h` file?

Comment: You are defining a global variable. You can interpret that as a "default", but to the compiler, it's just an instance of the struct. You could initialize that instance, but note that it is not advisable to define global variables in a header. If multiple files include that header, they will all get their own copy.

Comment: how would you get to those statements to run them? Execution starts at main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign values to members at the file scope because only declarations and definitions are allowed on the scope level.
While `defaultPlayer.health = 100` is an expression.

To set default values put it into struct initializer:

```
struct Player defaultPlayer = {
  .health = 100,
  .stamina = 100,
};
```

Moreover it may be a good idea to make it `const`.

You can make it an extern symbol. The `defaultPlayer` would only be *declared* in `main.h` and defined `main.c`.

```
// main.h
extern const struct Player defaultPlayer;

//main.c
const struct Player defaultPlayer = {
  .health = 100,
  .stamina = 100,
};
```

Cons: the compiler cannot inline values of members for translation units other than `main.c`.

Or use a static object in the header.

```
// main.h
static const struct Player defaultPlayer = {
  .health = 100,
  .stamina = 100,
};
```

Cons: compiler may complain about unused variables. What can be silenced by adding a dummy function:

```
static inline void dummy(void) { (void)&defaultPlayer; }
```

The third option is to make it a macro that expands to the compound literal.

```
#define defaultPlayer (const struct Player){ .health = 100, .stamina = 100 }
```

IMO, works the best.

Answer (score 1):

### A naive try:

A header defines the interface the object will offer to other objects. Therefore it should not contain any implementation detail.

Imagine you have the following files:

```c
/* pretty_print.h */
// header guard
void pretty_print(char* str);

/* pretty_print.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pretty_print.h"
void pretty_print(char* str) {
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

```c
#include "pretty_print.h"
int main() {
    pretty_print("Hey there");
}
```

There will be two objects generated: main.o and pretty_print.o
None of which is yet executable. Neither does main.o contain any function pretty_print.
Linking both together will provide main.o the necessary pretty_print function (as well as do some more stuff).

Now assume there is some sort of data, let's say `int x` in the pretty_print.h .
As main.o included the header file, there will be such an `x`. However, pretty_print.o will have an `x` as well, as it includes `pretty_print.h`. So there will be two `x` and the compiler can't know which one to choose.

### But I can declare the struct, I just can't change it's values

Yes you can, but you shouldn't declare instances in headers.
To answer, why you can't change it's values, remember there is a `main` function. When is this "global code" in your execution path? When is it intended to be run?

### Please just fix...

You can always use struct initialization in the following way:

```c
struct foo_t {
    int x;
};
struct foo_t foo = { .x = 42 };
```

If you run in any further errors I assume you have to use the `extern` keyword with a pointer to a player-struct and initalize it with a default player in main